# Variation of the kinetic term in modified gravity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Assume you have an action $S=\int \sqrt{-g}(R+p(X,\phi)) d^4x$.

I want to calculate the perturbations for $\phi(t,x)=\phi_0(t)+\delta \phi(t,x)$ and the standard perturbed metric $ds^2=(1+2\Phi)dt^2-(1-2\Phi)a^2(t)\gamma_{ik}dx^idx^k$.

I can't seem to figure how to calculate $\delta X$, where $X=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu} \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi$. What I do is $$\delta X= 1/2 (\delta(g^{\mu \nu} ) \partial_\mu \phi \partial_\nu \phi + 2 g^{\mu \nu}\delta (\partial_\mu \phi) \partial_\nu \phi) $$ and I know that $ \delta (\nabla_\mu \phi) =g^{\mu \nu}  \nabla_\nu \delta(\phi) +\delta(g^{\mu \nu} ) \nabla_\nu \phi  $. But I can't seem to figure what should be the final result for $\delta X$.  For example, what happens with term $\nabla_\nu \delta(\phi)$? I'd be very glad if anyone could point me to a reference or explain it to me.

Edit: Ok, the answer is, $\delta X = \dot{\phi(t)}\delta \dot{\phi}(t,x)-\Phi \dot{\phi}(t)^2$ (from another article). But my derivation is a bit hand-waving.

(the whole setup https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9904176, I'm stuck on Eq. 13).

Comment: Questions on this site are expected to be self-contained. A reader should not have to another site in order to understand your question.

Comment: I updated the question with the action and the perturbation. I didn't write a more detailed question because it's a pretty standard setup for GR and als I saw many other questions related to variation in GR so I assumed the question is self-contained. The article I gave was just for context.

Comment: Link does not work.

Comment: @ApolloRa, now it works, it was a typo.